# BIND9 and IPv6... why doesn't it listen?

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, bind

OS is Debian sid.  BIND 9.7.3.

It has no ACLs (except whatever's the not-overridden-in-config-file default), and has "listen-on-v6 { any; };" (as per Debian's default).

IPv6 is supported (ssh, smtp, http[s] and imaps all running on IPv6 sockets).  Ah, yes, it is dual-stack (of course).

BIND says "No IPv6 interfaces found" but, obviously, there *is* one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pilot error (and a very misleading error message): I had a "-4" in the options in /etc/default/bind9 (don't recall why I put it there, but I recall now that I did so)

The misleading error is that Bind reports not finding an interface when I expressly told it not to do IPv6.  It should report the latter.  Which it doesn't.

So, problem solved.